# Degree of polynomial expressing OR of n Boolean variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, computational-complexity

The question goes something like

> Show that the OR of $n$ variables cannot be expressed as a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of degree less than $n$.

I do not have the slightest clue of how to proceed with the proof. Of course, there is one such construction which will give a polynomial of degree exactly $n$. But for the proof I guess we need an abstract tool which proves that any polynomial of degree less than $n$ will not correctly or fully express the OR of $n$ variables.

<sub>*Source of the problem- Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach by Arora and Barak*</sub>

Comment: Can you explain how a polynomial over $\mathbb F_p$ can represent OR? I understand how this works when $p=2$, but what would this mean when $p=3$?

Comment: Polynomial can give non-zero values for a variable setting which makes the boolean function true. And 0 otherwise.

Comment: To clarify: the inputs to the polynomial are either $0$ or $1$ for each variable, and the output should be nonzero if any of the inputs are $1$, and zero otherwise?

Comment: That's right. I guess the reason this is valid is that 0 or 1 are just representations.

Comment: When $n=3$ and $p=5$, wouldn't $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$ represent the OR of three variables with a degree $2$ polynomial?

Comment: I think that the polynomial should be required to equal one when at least one variable is one, not just be nonzero.

Comment: I guess you are right. Else the polynomial will not be expressing the boolean function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have proven that OR, and any Boolean function, can be written as a polynomial over $\mathbb F_2$. You can say more; any Boolean function can be written as a *multilinear* polynomial. This is one where no squares $x_i^2$ appear. The is true for the simple reason that over $\mathbb F_2$, $x=x^2=x^3=\dots$, so higher powers are redundant.

A multlinear polynomial has terms that look like $x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\dots x_{i_k}$, where $\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\}\subset [n]$ are $k$ distinct indices. There are $2^n$ possible terms, so there are $2^{2^n}$ multilinear polynomials. Since there are exactly $2^{2^n}$ Boolean functions, this implies that the representation you have is **unique**, so if you can find one representation of OR as an $n$ degree polynomial, you know that there are no others, so can conclude no representation has degree less than $n$.

---

Assuming that "exrpessing" OR as a polynomial $f$ over $\mathbb F_p$ means that $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, restricted to $\{0,1\}^n$, must be equal to $1$ if any inputs are $1$ and equal to $0$ otherwise, then here is a proof that OR requires a degree at least $ n$ polynomial.

Again, it suffices to consider multilinear polynomials, since $0^k=0$ and $1^k=1$ for all $k\ge 1$, so higher powers are redundant.

I will prove the stronger claim that any function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to \mathbb F_p$ can be represented **uniquely** as a multilinear polynomial over $\mathbb F_p$. For existence, for any $v\in \{0,1\}^n$, there exists a multilinear polynomial $g_v$ for which $g_v(v)=1$ and $g_v(w)=0$ for all $w\neq 0$. The construction of $f_v$ is the same as the construction of AND. Then, any function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to \mathbb F_p$ can be represented as $$f(x)=\sum_{v\in \{0,1\}^n}f(v)g_v(x)$$

For uniqueness, the last equation shows that $B=\{g_v:v\in \{0,1\}^n\}$ is a spanning set for the $\mathbb F_p$ vector space of functions $\{0,1\}^n\to \mathbb F_p$. The cardinality of $B$ is $2^n$, and the dimension of the vector space of functions $\{0,1\}^n\to \mathbb F_p$ is $2^n$. Basic linear algebra then implies that $B$ is a basis for this vector space, so the representation is unqiue. Therefore, OR is represented uniquely as a multilinear polynomial, so its degree $n$ representation is the only one.

Comment: I could not follow through your idea of unique representation. How was that inferred from your previous observations? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Every Boolean function has a multilinear polynomial. There are the same number of Boolean functions as multilinear polynomials. Therefore, every function must have _exactly one_ polynomial. If there were any function with two polynomials, then there would not be enough polynomials to go around. @Prateek

Comment: Why is the function $f(x)$ represented in terms of itself? I'm curious to know about the $f(v)$ term in your expression. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Prateek The point is that $f(v)$ is a constant with respect to $x$, and $g_v(x)$ are all polynomials, so that expression writes $f(x)$ as a polynomial. The equality there is a silly one; the properties of $g_v$ discussed before ensure that the only nonzero term in the summation is the one where $v=x$, so the summation is $f(x)\cdot g_x(x)=f(x)\cdot 1$. Silly or not, it writes $f$ as a polynomial.